# Authentication in react-native: best approaches

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt

I'm building a react-native app where users can login. Because I'm a beginner, I'm not really sure what is the best approach on building a secure environment. I have planned out a strategy, but I need some feedback before going any further.

**Strategy**

After a successful login, the server returns an **auth token** and a **refresh token** (both jwt). The auth token is valid for 30 minutes, the refresh token is valid for 6 months. I store both tokens in keychain (ios) or shared preferences (android). Whenever a request (1) is made to the server, the auth token is send with the request in the Authorization header. Server-side, the auth token is checked for validity (is it expired or not?). If the token has expired, the server sends a response to the app containing 'please_refresh'. This should signal to the app that the refresh token has to be sent to the server to create a new auth token. When this is done, the original request (1) should be executed again with the new auth token.

```
// valid auth token
+-------------------+                                   +-------------------+ 
| CLIENT            |                                   | SERVER            |
|                   | ----- auth token to server -----> |                   |
| auth token: aaa   |                                   | auth token OK     |
| refresh token: bbb| <---- response to client   ------ |                   |
|                   |                                   |                   |
+-------------------+                                   +-------------------+

// invalid auth token
+-------------------+                                   +-------------------+ 
| CLIENT            |                                   | SERVER            |
|                   | ----- auth token to server -----> |                   |
| auth token: aaa   |                                   | auth token NOT OK |
| refresh token: bbb| <---- 'please_refresh_token' ---- |                   |
|                   |                                   |                   |
|                   | ----- refresh token to server --> | create new auth   |
|                   |                                   |             token |
| new auth tk: ccc  | <---- new auth token to client -- |                   |
|                   |                                   |                   |
|                   | ---> new auth token to server --- | auth token OK     |
|                   |                                   |                   |
|                   | <---- response to client    ----- |                   | 
+-------------------+                                   +-------------------+
```

Is this a good strategy to authenticate a user? Another approach would be to send the refresh token together with the auth token in the first request, and to renew the auth token immediately when it's expired.

My questions about this strategy are:

- Is this a good approach? Or is there room for improvements?
- After 6 months, the refresh token becomes invalid so the user has to login again. I don't really want this: I want to user to be logged in as long as he/she wants. How can I tackle this problem? Should I add a third token to "refresh the refresh token"? (This doesn't seem right to me).
- If this approach (auth/refresh token) is not the way to go, can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you use tried and tested protocols like [Open Id Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) instead of rolling out your own strategy. See [AppAuth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth)